# can't put text to .txt file using python

Tags: python, text-files, python-2.x

This is flow what i want in my program:
- Read latest data in text file
- add up latest data with specific data what i want
- write the sum into text file in starts at the beginning of the file

I've got what I want to make but there is an error. What should I do?
Here's my python code:

```
f = open('uangmasuk.txt', 'r+')
latest = f.readline()
data = int(latest) + 1000
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Here's my text file:

```
0
1000
2000
```

Error Message:

```
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(data)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: Please share with us the error message you are seeing. It's a great way to explain what issues you are facing. `"there is an error"` is really not something that helps the people providing assistance. Imagine if you were to receive a bug report that says `"there is an error"`.... not much to go by...

Comment: i've update the question @Lix

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a fix at `f.write`, which takes a string as parameter and not an integer:

```
f.write(str(data) + '\n')
#       |<- cast integer to string
#                   |<- add new line character
```

Comment: thx it's work, but the latest data is stored in the bottom, if it can be changed to the top?

Comment: @Eightleven I don't quite understand. Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: Use please the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement for I/O operations, it's much cleaner and handles opening/closing well.